# concatenation issues. The confirm message doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, concatenation

```
    $html .= '<a href =delete.php?pid='.$data['pid'].' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');">Delete Item |';
```

We are having a problem on concatenation. the onclick doesn't work. 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Are' (T_STRING) - this message appears.

Comment: The color coding in your code above shows you the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$html .= '<a href =delete.php?pid='.$data['pid'].' onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete?\');">Delete Item |';
```

You need to escape the single quotes around the confirm message.